# Obtaining real world long/lat from GeoTIFF file using GDAL and C#?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, c#

I am trying to obtain and convert latitude and longitude values into British National Grid coordinates from GeoTIFF using GDAL C# file, I managed to read the coordinate system and corner coordinates as shown in the below picture.

The thing is, since that GDAL is more of Python documentation and I can't go through it, I am not sure what is the next step or how to do it using `SpatialReference()` and `CoordinateTransformation()`.

This is the code I tried so far but still getting the wrong numbers, I think its because they are  projected coordinate system and needed to be converted in British coordinate system.

How can I do this?

[image]

```
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureOgr();
Gdal.AllRegister();

string fileName = @"path/DSM_D01.tif";
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
List<int> resolutionId = new List<int>() { 9 };
Dataset ds = Gdal.Open(fileName, Access.GA_ReadOnly);

double[] gt = new double[6];
ds.GetGeoTransform(gt);

int Rows = ds.RasterYSize;
int Cols = ds.RasterXSize;
Band band = ds.GetRasterBand(1);
double startX = gt[0];
double startY = gt[3];
double interval = gt[1];
double x, y;

for (int k = 0; k < Rows; k++)
{
    y = startY - k * interval; //Current lat
    int[] buf = new int[Cols];
    //ReadRaster parameters are StartCol, StartRow, ColumnsToRead, RowsToRead, BufferToStoreInto, BufferColumns, BufferRows, 0, 0
    band.ReadRaster(0, k, Cols, 1, buf, Cols, 1, 0, 0);
    //iterate each item in one line
    for (int r = 0; r < Cols; r++)
    {
        if (buf[r] != -32768)   //if pixel value is not NoData value
        {
            x = startX + r * interval;  //current lon 
            string BritishNationalGrid = 

            //Console.WriteLine("Lat: " + y + " Long: " + x);
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```